# Console output from bash command executed with wsl getting truncated when redirected to a file

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to use wsl to execute a bash command from powershell/cmd and capture the output to a file.

When I run `wsl -e cat /etc/services` the full contents of the file appears correctly in the console.

However, if I run `wsl -e cat /etc/services > foo.txt` the contents of the foo.txt only contain the first ~ 4k characters from the output. If I run the same command in wsl bash, the foo.txt contains the full content I would expect. I've tried this with a number of wsl commands, and the cutoff point always seems to be about 4k characters. I've also tried `wsl -- cat /etc/services > foo.txt` with the same results.

Does anyone know why the truncation is happening? More importantly, how do I run a command with wsl and capture the output to a file?

Comment: Probably an input buffer limitation, but I couldn't find a way to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Do you have reference for that? I haven't run across this before

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4082